# Helm Template iterating over map to create multiple jobs

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I'm trying to iterate over map in Helm chart to create multiple Kubernetes Cronjobs. Since I had trouble generating multiple manifests from a single template I used '---' to separate the manifests. Otherwise it kept generating only a one manifest.

```
{{- range $k, $job := .Values.Jobs }}
{{- if  $job.enabled }}
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ $job.name }}
  namespace: {{ $.Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  schedule: {{ $job.schedule }}
  startingDeadlineSeconds: xxx
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: x
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: x
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: {{ $job.name }}
            image: {{ $.Values.cronJobImage }}
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - curl {{ $.Values.schedulerBaseUrl }}/{{ $job.url }}
          restartPolicy: Never
---
{{- end }}
{{ end }}
```

values.yaml

```
Jobs:
- name: "xxx-job"
  enabled: true
  schedule: "00 18 * * *"
  url: "jobs/xxx"

- name: "xxx-job"
  enabled: true
  schedule: "00 18 * * *"
  url: "jobs/xxx"
```

From this way it works and generates all the Jobs defined in the values.yaml. I was wandering is there an any better way to do this?

Comment: I'd tweak a couple of things (include `.Release.Name` in the CronJob name, put `---` at the start of the block, avoid the `sh -c` wrapper) but essentially this is the right approach.  Is there a specific problem you're encountering?

Comment: @DavidMaze I couldn't find a proper way to do it and wondering is there some other way just than printing '---'

Comment: Using the `---` YAML start-of-document marker is right.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation and am having trouble writing tests; we are using https://github.com/quintush/helm-unittest/blob/master/DOCUMENT.md for unit tests.
The problem is, which document index, in this case, do we have to use to separate manifest? For example, in the case above, iterate four times, and in two cases will fail!

Comment: answer seems like a question